# azure data factory: use variables in query

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created a copy activity that copies data from an on premise database to a Azure SQL Database.
I need to modify dynamiccaly the query, so it takes a range of dates, with these two variables:

- `inidate`
- `enddate`

Which I want to use inside the `where` clause, but I don't know how to reference the variables. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
  SELECT * FROM tableOnPrem 
  WHERE dateOnPrem BETWEEN '@variable('inidate')' AND '@variable('enddate')'
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 8):

I found that adding curly braces was enough to get this working (and like [Joel Cochran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62217164/6722583) stated using the *plural* variable**s** keyword):

```
SELECT * FROM tableOnPrem 
WHERE dateOnPrem 
BETWEEN '@{variables('inidate')}' AND '@{variables('enddate')}'
```

However, it still reports an error on the Source "Preview data" option, but despite this it runs correctly in the actual pipeline run.

Answer (score 2):

In a Pipeline (like for Copy activity), you will need to build the query string dynamically using the [Pipeline Expression Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) (PEL). The best way to do this is to use the [concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#concat) function to piece together the query:

```
@concat('SELECT * FROM tableOnPrem WHERE dateOnPrem BETWEEN ''',variables('inidate'),''' AND ''',variables('enddate'),'''')
```

This can get complex rather quickly, so you'll need to pay extra attention to commas, parentheses, ''' and ''''.

Note that the '@' symbol only appears once, at the beginning of the expression. Also, to reference a pipeline variable you are calling the "variable**s**" function.

Comment: String concatenation is vulnerable to SQL injection *and* conversion issues. What happens if `enddate` contains `'00010101'; drop table users;--` ? Or `'"potato"` ? Or `31.12.2020` ?

Comment: Valid points to be sure, especially in web development, but data factory pipelines should operate in a controlled/closed system. If your internal actors are sending strings like this, I think you have bigger problems. I was answering the question that was asked, but a Stored Procedure would be another viable option.

Answer (score 2):

Another option to handle is define them as pipeline parameters [pipeline-prameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameters-data-flow). Say for example if you have parameters defined as

- start_date
- end_date

you can have query written like below

```
SELECT * FROM tableOnPrem WHERE dateOnPrem BETWEEN @{pipeline().parameters.start_date} AND @{pipeline().parameters.end_date}
```