# Azure Data Factory V2 Using Params in SQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

New to ADF in general and hitting a speed bump with the following scenario, would really appreciate any guidance on how to achieve this.

In my pipeline I want to use simple SQL to control how much data I process, so using:

```
SELECT * FROM DPA.USER_REGISTRATIONS 
WHERE REG_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-01-01' AND DATE '2020-06-09'
```

Using the 'preview data' button/tool in ADF UI this returns a sample of exactly what I am looking for. Great, but I need the second DATE value to always be the current date. I'm sure this must be very simple but I can't seem to find the right way to form the params/expressions to get it to work.

I am trying:

```
SELECT * FROM DPA.USER_REGISTRATIONS 
WHERE REG_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2020-01-01' AND DATE @pipeline.parameters.today;
```

Where I have a pipeline level parameter defined with name: today and value: utcnow()
But that doesn't work.

Can someone please advise on how to create and reference a suitable param?
Thanks!

Comment: what about creating a stored procedure and move this query to it and also use GetDATE() rather than receiving the date as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

To do this based on dynamic values, you will need to use the Pipeline Expression Language (PEL) (and most likely variables) to build the query string. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213623/azure-data-factory-use-variables-in-query/62217164#62217164) may prove useful to you.