# Azure Data Factory System Variable Pipeline Trigger Time Date Conversion Error "The function call must take the completion string"

Tags: azure-data-factory

In ADF, I'm trying to take the system variable for the pipeline trigger time and convert it from UTC to EST with just the date format and not the time (yyyy-MM-dd).

Should be straightforward but I keep getting this non-descript error:

> The function call must take the completion string

`convertFromUtc(@pipeline().TriggerTime, 'Eastern Standard Time', 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

Also tried converting it to string first and get the same error:

`convertFromUtc(string(@pipeline().TriggerTime), 'Eastern Standard Time', 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213623/azure-data-factory-use-variables-in-query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a small change, it apparently should be as below, with `@` at the beginning.

```
@convertFromUtc(pipeline().TriggerTime, 'Eastern Standard Time', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was it!!