# SQL Query using script activity in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the script activity in ADF pipeline:

[image]

On running this, I see the following error. What does this indicate and how do fix this?

[image]

Comment: You need to qualify the @variable, otherwise the sql is looking for a temp table. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213623/azure-data-factory-use-variables-in-query

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make tableName dynamic. It won't work like that. Better create a variable and use Set variable activity to set the tableName. Then use the same in your script Activity.

`select * from @{variables('tableName')} where id=@id`

Set variable activity settings:
[image]

Here is the script activity settings:
[image]

Output :
[image]